# Remove tiny scroll bar - Ionic 3

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2, ionic3

You can see that there is a tiny scroll bar as shown below.Can you tell me how to remove that? This is `Ionic 3` app. I have tried many ways.But no luck yet.

Please see how bad it is on the device :(

[image]

This on the browser:

[image]

*.sass*

```
 .height-70 {
        height: 70px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

*.html*

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col class="height-70" col-12>
        <ion-content>
          <button ion-button icon-left full (click)="loginWithLinkedin()" class="background-color-linkedin"><ion-icon name="logo-linkedin" class="margin-top-minus-4"></ion-icon><span>Continue with Linkedin</span></button>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Chrome css(run time): below `padding:16px` is the problem.But how can I remove it? Because I need padding too.Any workaround?

[image]

Comment: `overflow: hidden` [CSS overflow property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

Comment: It is not working no? Where to put that? @PatrickMlr

Comment: "Where to put?" that depends on which element causes the scroll bar. check it using browser debugging tool can change specific class as @PatrickMlr mentioned

Comment: I have done it for all the places where I can think of.But no luck.One location I have put it with my question.Please see it.@ShanilFernando

Comment: `class="height-70" col-12` is typo error?

Comment: Why? No.That is Ionic grid attribute (i.e. `col-12`)http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid  @Nawin

Comment: Seem like that scrollbar does not belong sroll-content. Try to delete element in chrome inspect till the scrollbar disapear you will find where does it come from.

Comment: why are you using ion-content inside ion-col?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `ion-content` inside `ion-col` it will add some properties from `scroll-content`. **Replace `ion-content` with div** and manually add all the css properties you want to your `div`.

Comment: I wouldn't be sure even why a div is needed, since the `ion-col` is a container itself, but that'd be more like a question for the owner of the post. +1 because I also think that the `ion-content` should not be placed there.

Comment: Excellent.Thanks :)

Comment: the answer by Joao Mello doesn't need introduction/replacement of other elements like div

Answer (score 3):

```
.scroll-content {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why this answer without votes but it worked for me! thanks

Comment: Thank you for feedback, this is important.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this file app.scss under /src/app/

```
[scrollbar-y-auto] .scroll-content {
  overflow-y: false !important;
}
```

and
Your code :

```
<ion-content scrollbar-y-auto>
```

Not tested Check and let me know

Comment: Not working and it is not generating anything on the chrome too?

Comment: Thanks this work perfect for me. I have only to change false to "hidden" :)

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following,

```
<ion-content overflow-scroll="false">
```

1.bounce,

```
<ion-content no-bounce></ion-content>
```

2.

```
.content > .scroll-content::before {
    bottom: 0;
}

.content > .scroll-content::after {
    top: 0;
}
```

3.

```
.scroll-content {
   overflow-y: auto !important;
}
```

4.

```
<ion-content>
   <div ion-fixed>
   </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: No.Still, it is not working.Your attribute doesn't generate any CSS on chrome.Why?

Comment: added a few more try them out, im not that sure with ionic3

Answer (score 0):

What I have experienced is sometimes you see scrollbar in browser but not on device. I would suggest to you to verify the same in device or try chrome device emulator in dev tools by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+M`.

Comment: You can try removing `height-70` class from `ion-col`, if you need vertical spacing between buttton (as can be seen in image) add blank div with some height.